# DB2 Update with join queries

Tags: join, db2

I am using DB2 for performing the below update operation.

```
update DATA set B_DESC=P_DESC, P_DESC=null
where B_DESC= *, P_DESC=*
(Select B_DESC,P_DESC from C_DATA)
```

The below is actually possible but since complex joins are involved in that sub query it is not advisable to use like below

```
update DATA set B_DESC=P_DESC, P_DESC=null
where B_DESC= (Select B_DESC from C_DATA), P_DESC=(Select P_DESC from C_DATA)
```

I have to update DATA table, but the B_DESC and P_DESC i have to fetch it from C_DATA table and use it in the UPDATE query.

Please let me know how to do it. It has to be a single query if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a merge query to update the table, instead of join. DB2 does not accept join in update query for that purpose, you have to use a merge:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_NAME1 A 
    USING (SELECT  COL1, COL2  FROM TABLE_NAME2) B
    ON A.COL1 = B.COL2
    WHEN MATCHED AND A.COL1 = B.COL2
    THEN UPDATE SET A.COL1 = B.COL2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your 1st query not work?  I'm not familiar with comma-separating parts of the `WHERE` clause (it's not valid on my version of DB2 - is it actually part of the syntax?).

Normally, when I need to run these types of update queries, I use an `EXISTS` clause, like this:

```
UPDATE data as a SET b_desc = p_desc, p_desc = null
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT '1'
              FROM c_data as b
              WHERE b.b_desc = a.b_desc
              AND b.p_desc = a.p_desc)
```

Comment: `@X-Zero` I dont think, `AND b.p_desc = a.p_desc` is needed in `WHERE` clause, which may restrict many updates. 

`@rozar`What do you say?

Comment: @RajaReddy - He had (what I took to be) an `AND` clause to begin with, so that's what I chose.